# Can we sparse solve a few eigenvalues specified by index range?

Tags: linear-algebra, python, sparse-matrix, eigenvalues, intel-mkl

I need to solve a few eigenvalues of a large sparse matrix specified by their index range. These indices are according to the whole eigenspectrum sorted in algebraic (not absolute value) ascending order.

For example in python, I notice this is made available by the subset_by_index option in [scipy.linalg.eigh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html) for non-sparse matrices, but not in the sparse counterpart [eigsh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html). In MKL, we have non-sparse routines like [heevx](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/_heevx.htm) with the similar option but I don't find clear info in the sparse docs.

Is this possible at all in the sparse context?